# IP exploring with Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I want to divide group of IPs by their provider. Let say I have 1000 IPs from my apache access log and I want to divide them in a Kibana visualize, sorted by provider - amazon, google, etc. Is this possible to be done with kibana or do you have any suggestions for another tool, which can do this ?

Comment: I imagine you would split your visualisation for terms related to your IP field. You can preprocess the data and simply resolve the name into a new field based on the IP (or potentially use a script field) which you could then use for splitting your visualisation, too.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but how to match which IP to which provider belongs ? I already have providers IP ranges, but not sure how to match this in kibana

Comment: This you would normally do at a step before (i.e. using logstash to parse the apache access logs and populate the provider). You could in kibana use a filter (aggregation) and build a matching query for the ranges that you want, labelling that filter with the correct provider.

Comment: Ok, but do you have suggestion how to make logstash to populate the provider ?

Comment: For this you can use the translate filter, documented here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/lookup-enrichment.html#translate-def